# Variables Defined in rSpec Not Changing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have a simple model called queue_item with an attribute called "list_order" that allows users to change the order of an item's appearance on a page.  I have a simple rSpec test that verifies whether the "list_order" attribute changes after a post to a controller action.  My test continually fails with this error message:

```
 QueueItemsController POST sort_list_order user is authenticated input is valid Assigns list_order
 Failure/Error: expect(item1.list_order).to eq(3)

   expected: 3
        got: 1
```

This is very odd to me because when I place a binding.pry in the controller action after my code changes the "list_order" attributes, it shows that all of the queue_item objects have been successfully updated.  Additionally, the UI functionality works as expected.  Why is the rSpec test not reflecting the controller action's changes to the objects?

**Controller Action:**

```
def sort_list_order
    counter = 1
    array = params[:queue_items].sort_by{ |k,v| v }
    array.each do |k,v|
      item = QueueItem.find(k.to_i) 
      puts item.list_order
      item.update(list_order:counter)
      puts item.list_order
      counter +=1
    end
    binding.pry
```

end

**Test:**

```
    it "Assigns list_order" do
      item1 = Fabricate(:queue_item)
      item2 = Fabricate(:queue_item)
      item3 = Fabricate(:queue_item)

      post :sort_list_order, queue_items:{item1.id=>3 ,item2.id =>2 ,item3.id => 1 }

      expect(item1.list_order).to eq(3)
      expect(item2.list_order).to eq(2)
      expect(item3.list_order).to eq(1)
    end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to reload the objects from the database, since the in-memory objects declared in the spec have not changed.

```
  expect(item1.reload.list_order).to eq(3)
  expect(item2.reload.list_order).to eq(2)
  expect(item3.reload.list_order).to eq(1)
```